# Most efficient way to not repeat a database call inside of a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm writing a model instance method that should find an AR association if it exists, or create it if it doesn't. How can I do this so that after the first find, the database isn't queried again? I have two version of this method below but both have drawbacks.

This method performs the query every time which is inefficient.

```
  def cart
    carts.order('created_at desc').where(:purchased_at => nil).first || carts.create
  end
```

This method only does the db lookup once, but gets out of sync after something like cart.destroy.

```
  def cart
    @cart_ || @cart_ = carts.order('created_at desc').where(:purchased_at => nil).first || @cart_ = carts.create
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord Relations have a little-known feature that allows you to create an instance from them:

```
User.where(name: 'John').new #=> <User @name="John">
```

Combine that with `find_or_create` and you're on your way:

```
Cart.order('created_at DESC').find_or_create_by_purchased_at(nil)
```

Every time you call `cart` Rails will run a query, *however* it is very performant because it'll hit the query cache which expires at the end of the request. Assuming you're not clearing all carts in between calls to this method, you should be fine.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. I'll think I'll go with this, but I can't tell if it's hitting the query cache.

Comment: I *think* query caching only happens during actual requests. Do a `tail -f log/development.log` and check output during an actual request and you'll see `CACHE` in place of `Cart Load` if it's using the cache appropriately.

Comment: PS: 5ms for a simple query like this is *really* slow. You would probably see much better performance out of MySQL or Postgres, which I'm hoping you would be using in production. Still good to eliminate extra queries, but you're talking about this taking 0.5ms in the real-world, or 1/10th of what you're seeing here.